# Plotting Linear Regression Line with Confidence Interval

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, confidence-interval

I am trying to plot how 'Square feet' of a home affects 'Sales Price (in $1000)' of the same. Particularly, I want the coefficient line from Square ft vs. Sales price plotted with a hypothetical grey area around the line with the original datapoints superimposed.

I have tried to complete this a few different ways. One way I have tried is using the function effect_plot from library(jtools). I used the coding I found from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jtools/vignettes/effect_plot.html.

But when I run this function, I don't get a plot, I just get an error: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object '`Sales Price (in $1000)`' not found.

The second way I have attempted is through manually creating a new vector and attempting to plot the confidence interval. My code inspiration is from [Plotting a 95% confidence interval for a lm object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46459620/plotting-a-95-confidence-interval-for-a-lm-object).

But with this one, I get an error in the conf_interval line: Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Square feet' not found. I cannot figure out how to correct this error.

And finally, I have tried to use library(ggplot2) to complete the problem with inspiration from https://rpubs.com/aaronsc32/regression-confidence-prediction-intervals.

But each time I run R, it creates a coordinate plane with a single point in the center of the plane; there is no line, no real points, no hypothetical confidence interval. There are no errors and I also cannot figure out the issue with the coding.

```
library("jtools")
LRA1 <- lm(`Sales Price (in $1000)` ~ `Square feet` + Rooms +
 Bedrooms + Age,data=HomedataSRS) #LRA1 is the regression model
effect_plot(LRA1, pred = 'Square feet', inherit.aes = FALSE,
 plot.points = TRUE) #function should create graph
```

```
newSF = seq(min(HomedataSRS$`Square feet`),
            max(HomedataSRS$`Square feet`), by = 0.05)
conf_interval <- predict(LRA1, newdata=data.frame(x=newSF),
                 interval="confidence",level = 0.95)
plot(HomedataSRS$`Square feet`, HomedataSRS$`Sales Price (in $1000)`,
     xlab="Square feet", ylab="Sales Price(in $1000)",     
     main="Regression")
abline(LRA1, col="lightblue")
matlines(newSF, conf_interval[,2:3], col = "blue", lty=2)
```

```
library(ggplot2)
SFHT <- HomedataSRS %>% select(1:2) 
#This is to select the 2 variables I'm working with
ggplot(SFHT, aes(x='Square feet', inherit.aes = FALSE, 
       y='Sales Price (in $1000)')) +
       geom_point(color='#2980B9', size = 4) +
       geom_smooth(method=lm, color='#2C3E50')
```

Data:
[image: I take an n=35 random sample of this data with set.seed(1)]

Comment: Have you tried [`ggpmisc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54135578/786542)?

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data (or some fake data)?

Comment: @A.S.K., I took an n=35 sample of the data I posted with set.seed(1)

Comment: Thanks!  Could you also add code output (using `dput(HomedataSRS)`, or a subset thereof)?  That make it much easier to copy sample data so we can test possible solutions before posting them.

Answer (score 1):

arguments to `aes()` should not be quoted. Try

```
ggplot(SFHT, aes(x = `Square feet`, y = `Sales Price (in $1000)`)) +
   geom_point(color='#2980B9', size = 4) +
   geom_smooth(method=lm, color='#2C3E50')
```

alternatively, you could use the new `aes_string()` function:

```
ggplot(SFHT, aes_string(x='Square feet',y='Sales Price (in $1000)')) +
   geom_point(color='#2980B9', size = 4) +
   geom_smooth(method=lm, color='#2C3E50')
```

more info is available on the package site: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_.html