# To manully plot the CI

Tags: r, linear-regression, confidence-interval

How to find the CI of a simple linear regression model? I found different ways to do it but the CIs plotted are different from each other.

Since I am not from a statistics background so I am not sure which one is the correct one. I only have a very basic understanding of CI and linear regression.

The first attempt, I just use the function confint() to plot the straight line.

```r
plot(y~x, data=df)

abline(lm.model)

ci<-confint(lm.model, level=0.95)
abline(ci[1], ci[2])
abline(ci[3], ci[4])
```

Second attempt from [Plotting a 95% confidence interval for a lm object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46459620/plotting-a-95-confidence-interval-for-a-lm-object)

```
newx = seq(min(x),max(x),by = 0.05)
conf_interval <- predict(lm.model, newdata=data.frame(x=newx), interval="confidence",
                         level = 0.95)
plot(y~x, data=df, xlab="x", ylab="y", main="Regression")
abline(lm.model, col="lightblue")
lines(newx, conf_interval[,2], col="blue", lty=2)
lines(newx, conf_interval[,3], col="blue", lty=2)
```

It seems to me that they are all getting the same thing but I am not sure which one is the one I am looking for.
Any help is appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using `geom_smooth`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", level = 0.95)
```

[image]

Comment: So the second attempt is the correct  CI built? Then what is wrong about the first one ?

Comment: @user16971617 `confint` function returns CI of parameters, not for predicted values. For more information, see [confint function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/confint). Second attempt is correct.

Comment: Sorry that I still don't understand the difference of CI of parameters and predicted values. Aren't they the same?

Comment: For example ci gives

                  2.5 %      97.5 %
(Intercept)  5.27648921  7.03001947
x           -0.06696724 -0.02342506

Which means we are 95% confident that x is between region of abline(ci[1], ci[2]) and 
abline(ci[3], ci[4])

Comment: @user16971617 CI for `beta_0 hat`(`b0`) and `beta_1 hat`(`b1`) are `b0 +- t*sd(b0)`/`b1 +- t*sd(b1)` , for mean response is `y hat +- t * sqrt(MSE * (1/n +(x-xbar)^2/Sxx))` CI for new `x` is `y hat +- t * sqrt(MSE * (1+ 1/n +(x-x bar)^2/Sxx))`. Take a look at those components. They're pretty different.