# Plot for confidence intervals in R

Tags: r, plot, intervals, confidence-interval

I have data of parameters' names, their upper and lower bounds

For exaple:

```
x1 -1 -3
x2 -1  4
x3  3  5
```

etc.

Need some help to plot it like this: 
[image]

Comment: Are those numbers the highs and low? Where does the position of the circle come from?

Comment: yes, the numbers are the highs and lows. position of the circle doesnt matter

Comment: I typed "R plot confidence interval" in google images and there was pretty much at the top the same image. You can look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069629/how-can-i-plot-data-with-confidence-intervals

Comment: The highs and lows are already the upper and lower confidence intervals?