# abline plot confidence intervals

Tags: r, plot

I would like to plot a figure like the attached one. Consider just one color, let's say, the blue line.
The figure shows correlation between twinA and twinB.
The line in the figure is the mean of 1000 lines obtained with a permutation.
 I averaged slope and intercept and got the averaged regression line.
So far so good.

Then, I need to plot CIs. 
I need to use CIs I get from the permutation itself rather than the average CIs.
Therefore, I computed the CIs of the correlation coefficients  (between twinA and twinB) vector I obtained with the permutations.

Here's comes the issue.
With this code I am able to plot the line but I cannot find how to insert CI with abline function:

```
plot(1, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", xlim=c(0, 10), ylim=c(0, 20))

a=10.09773458
b = 0.183630788
abline(a, b)

CI=0.001940921
```

Any suggestion?
Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for something like `abline(a+CI, b, col="gray", lty=5)`?

Comment: using the script you suggested I do not get the CI plotted, but a line wit different intercept since a+CI simply add CI to the intercept.

Comment: How does your expected output look like?

Comment: like the image attached. I would line a line with CIs

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry, couldn't see the image before. Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069629/how-can-i-plot-data-with-confidence-intervals) help you?